# ¿Cómo se convirtió el verbo "torturar" en el verbo "trabajar"?

Tags: etimología, verbos

Dado que hoy celebramos el día del trabajo, toca preguntarse: etimológicamente, ¿qué es el trabajo?

Según el DLE, el [trabajo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aBuhX28) es toda ocupación retribuida, además de la acción y efecto de [trabajar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aBpHmn0). Lo que sorprende es la etimología de este verbo:

> Del lat. vulg. **tripaliāre* 'torturar', der. del lat. tardío *tripalium* 'instrumento de tortura compuesto de tres maderos'.

¿Cómo pasó un verbo que en latín vulgar significaba *torturar* a significar "ocuparse en cualquier actividad física o intelectual" o "tener una ocupación remunerada en una empresa, una institución, etc."?

Comment: Pues, al pensar en cómo era la mayoría de los trabajos a lo largo de la historia, es fácil ver por qué. Es lo mismo con *labor* (que en latín, también signifiqué *enfermedad*).

Comment: segun recuerdo o quiero recordar, creo que el "trabajo" en la antiguedad del imperio romano solo lo realizaban los esclavos

Comment: La etimología habitual de *travail*, y por consecuencia de trabajo esta cuestionada par varios lingüistas. Aqui son dos documentos en francés sobre esta controversia: https://blogs.mediapart.fr/jean-luce-morlie/blog/280911/tripalium-une-etymologie-ecran-archive y https://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_2008_num_126_503_1436

Comment: @jlliagre tus aportes son muy interesantes. Entiendo que la etimología está discutida. De hecho Covarrubias en 1611 decía que _trabajar_ venía de _trevejar_ o _treversar_, "volver las cosas de una parte a otra".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal vez la conexión se haga más patente si miramos el significado de la palabra en otros idiomas. Por ejemplo [en inglés](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/travail):

> TRAVAIL.
>   1 a : work especially of a painful or laborious nature
>     b : a physical or mental exertion or piece of work
>     c : agony, torment
>   2 : labor, childbirth

Es de particular interés esa acepción como "agonía, tormento". Hace además el Merriam-Webster alusión a la etimología mencionada, pero escribiendo el término del latín vulgar como "trepalium".

El significado de "trabajo" como "tormento" vendría derivado del instrumento de tortura, y puede ser el significado que se le podría dar a la palabra en este texto:

> *En es dia, de cierto, que no es Dios con ellos, por que es esto que alcançarlo an muchas malezas e travaios.*
>
> (En ese día, seguro que Dios no estará con ellos, y por eso les alcanzarán muchas malezas [males] y trabajos [tormentos].)
>
> Almerich, "La fazienda de Ultra Mar", c1200 (España).

El [CRNTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/travail) también considera la acepción de "tormento" (de nuevo la conexión con la tortura) para la palabra francesa "travail" hacia el siglo XII, junto con otras como "fatiga" y una acepción muy interesante: "dolor que nos damos a nosotros mismos, esfuerzos". Es cierto que cuando uno se esfuerza físicamente se está infligiendo un dolor. Encontramos aquí la conexión pues entre el tormento y el trabajo: el esfuerzo. De hecho en el siglo XIII se tiene ya la acepción de la palabra como "dolor que uno se inflige en el ejercicio de un oficio artesanal".

De hecho en España en el siglo XIII la palabra ya tenía ese significado:

> *Et las callonas de los pesos falsos e de las medidas e de los cotos, qui los crebantare, recabdelos el almotacen poral concejo e el concejo ponganle su soldada, por razon de su trabajo.*
>
> Anónimo, "Normativa [Documentos de Alfonso X dirigidos a Castilla la Vieja]", 1257 (España).

Con el paso del tiempo, en España la palabra "trabajo" perdió la parte del significado relativa al esfuerzo y las acepciones referentes al tormento. De hecho, llegado el siglo XV, Antonio de Nebrija incluía la palabra "trabajar" en su diccionario como "laboro", que en latín hace referencia al "esfuerzo que se hace cuando se intenta conseguir cualquier cosa". Y en el siglo XVII Covarrubias definía "trabajo" como "el cuidado y diligencia que ponemos en obrar alguna cosa, especialmente las que son manuales". Reminiscencias todavía al trabajo físico, más propenso a causar ese dolor de los antiguos significados de la palabra.

Como nota curiosa, el Merriam-Webster afirma que la palabra "travail", que el inglés importó del francés en el siglo XIII, generó un siglo más tarde el significado de "viajar", haciendo que el verbo "to travel" descienda también de aquel instrumento de tortura.

Comment: Charlie, ¿quieres agregar una traducción de *travail*?  ¿Quizás *pena*?

Comment: @aparente001 creo que en este caso _pena_ se refiere a su tercera acepción [según el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SQbVLbD): "dolor, tormento", significado que ya está cubierto en la respuesta.